# Word for being treated disrespectfully

Tags: connotation

I want to know if it is correct to say:

“The kind of contempt sex workers receive from society ...”

I mean we usually say, “the kind of respect he earned ...”

I believe “earn” would not be right choice for abuse, contempt, or disgust. So is it fine to use “receive” here?

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to say "they were dissed" ... but my dictionary says "dis" in only "being spoken to disrespectfully" and not "being treated disrespectfully".

Answer (score 1):

"Receive" is absolutely the right choice in context when "earn" seems to be inappropriate with negative words. The advantage of "receive" is that it has neither positive nor negative connotations. Thus you can say

> the contempt they receive
>
> the respect they receive

and "receive" is appropriate in either case.

Even "earn" can be used in certain negative situations and it still makes perfect sense in context, as long as something is "earned" as a result of some action:

> The contempt that sex workers earn is hypocritical considering how Society has always needed their services.
>
> The hostility our politicians earned from our own people (as a result of their corrupt ways) was very well-deserved.